Google Play Console crash report
I’m getting the following error report but I can’t figure out what’s causing it. This is happening  on
Infinix-X688B with Android 11 (SDK 30)
samsung a3core  with Android 13 (SDK 33)
TECNO-BG6 Android 13 (SDK 33)
POCO aresin Android 13 (SDK 33)
crashs happen approximately every three days or more, not very often
The number of active users on my application every day is more then 1k
I think the problem is because this code
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RowViewHolder holder, int position) {
       ......
              holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                int old_postion =-1;
                old_postion = position;
                if(old_postion == position){
                    int colorBlue = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.getContext(), R.color.black);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(colorBlue);
                    notifyItemChanged(old_postion);
                }
            });
    }

java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.getPosition (RecyclerView.java)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findReferenceChild (LinearLayoutManager.java)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findFirstReferenceChild (LinearLayoutManager.java)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findReferenceChildClosestToStart (LinearLayoutManager.java:7)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.updateAnchorFromChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:7)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.updateAnchorInfoForLayout (LinearLayoutManager.java:7)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:7)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2 (RecyclerView.java)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure (RecyclerView.java:2)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7109)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure (ConstraintLayout.java:23)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:7)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:43)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem (BasicMeasure.java:8)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure (BasicMeasure.java:62)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure (ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:62)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem (ConstraintLayout.java:62)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure (ConstraintLayout.java:62)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7109)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7109)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7109)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7109)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1552)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:721)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:7109)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:762)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:26488)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:4079)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3059)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2510)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9266)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1234)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1242)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:902)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:835)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1217)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8194)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:703)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:911)

I could not trace or determine the crash because everything seems good
on Recycleview Adapter

Please also place code where this issue is generating , it will be helpful to understand the problem

Look for "Logs and Breadcrumbs" section on the Crashlytics page. They can help you assess the screen on which  you see the logs

Hi.
I can't reproduce it at all.
i got this only crash logs from Google Play so no indication of where it's coming from
My app is 99.9% crash free, so this issue is pretty much the only issue that has yet to be fixed, but that happens very rarely.
So I don’t understand why this is happening and how to get rid of it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
